# how to find maximum available date of the month in dataframe in PANDAS/PYTHON

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, data-science

lets say i have a dataframe

```
date,ent_id,val
2021-03-23,109,61
2021-03-12,104,64
2021-03-31,101,61
2021-03-30,103,64
2021-04-01,111,32
2021-04-01,153,39
2021-04-30,101,51
2021-04-30,103,53
2021-05-12,101,28
2021-05-07,103,26
2021-05-05,171,47
2021-05-05,183,61
2021-06-06,131,45
2021-06-06,133,78
2021-06-30,101,23
2021-06-30,103,31
```

i want to find out the `maximum available date`  of the month

i know how to do this in sql

```
max(date) over (partition by date_part(year,date),date_part(month,date))
```

but i am unable to find out any logic in pandas or is there any build-in function for this

so the output would be like

```
date,ent_id,val,max_avl_d
2021-03-23,109,61,2021-03-31
2021-03-12,104,64,2021-03-31
2021-03-31,101,61,2021-03-31
2021-03-30,103,64,2021-03-31
2021-04-01,111,32,2021-04-30
2021-04-01,153,39,2021-04-30
2021-04-30,101,51,2021-04-30
2021-04-30,103,53,2021-04-30
2021-05-12,101,28,2021-05-12
2021-05-07,103,26,2021-05-12
2021-05-05,171,47,2021-05-12
2021-05-05,183,61,2021-05-12
2021-06-06,131,45,2021-06-30
2021-06-06,133,78,2021-06-30
2021-06-30,101,23,2021-06-30
2021-06-30,103,31,2021-06-30
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution you can try out,

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%Y-%m-%d')

df['max_date'] = (
    df.groupby([df['date'].dt.year, df['date'].dt.month])['date'].transform('max')
)
```

---

```
         date  ent_id  val   max_date
0  2021-03-23     109   61 2021-03-31
1  2021-03-12     104   64 2021-03-31
2  2021-03-31     101   61 2021-03-31
...
```

Comment: You can take advantage of [`to_period`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.to_period.html) here :) `df.groupby(df['date'].dt.to_period('M'))['date'].transform('max')`

Comment: Interesting.. did know about that.. thanks @anky

Answer (score 0):

We can levearage to_period() and to_timestamp() to get the last date of provided month date.

```
df['max_avl_d'] =  df.date.dt.to_period('M').dt.to_timestamp('M')
```

Output:

```
    date    ent_id  val max_avl_d
0   2021-03-23  109 61  2021-03-31
1   2021-03-12  104 64  2021-03-31
2   2021-03-31  101 61  2021-03-31
3   2021-03-30  103 64  2021-03-31
4   2021-04-01  111 32  2021-04-30
5   2021-04-01  153 39  2021-04-30
6   2021-04-30  101 51  2021-04-30
7   2021-04-30  103 53  2021-04-30
8   2021-05-12  101 28  2021-05-31
9   2021-05-07  103 26  2021-05-31
10  2021-05-05  171 47  2021-05-31
11  2021-05-05  183 61  2021-05-31
12  2021-06-06  131 45  2021-06-30
13  2021-06-06  133 78  2021-06-30
14  2021-06-30  101 23  2021-06-30
15  2021-06-30  103 31  2021-06-30
```